# How to add richfaces to maven project

Tags: maven, jsf-2, richfaces, glassfish-3

I'm trying to use popup component in my app. I use JSF, Glassfish. Here's my **pom.xml**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.karta</groupId>
    <artifactId>epacjent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>epacjent</name>

    <properties>       
        <org.richfaces.bom.version>4.2.2.Final</org.richfaces.bom.version>
        <gae.version>1.4.2</gae.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${org.richfaces.bom.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
            <id>eclipselink</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library Library[eclipselink]</name>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

and **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
        <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
        <param-value>enable</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
...
```

I've got this warnings:

```
WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file ajax.reslib.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file base-component.reslib.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file popupPanel.ecss.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
```

I'm really new to all this stuff, could someone tell me how should my configuration look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your problem is that **you're not adding the dependencies at all**.You only have the BOM added, but you need to add the other dependencies as the tutorial of [using Richfaces with Maven](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToAddRichFaces4xToMavenBasedProject) says. Adding the BOM you're only declaring which version of the library you want to use, but not attaching the dependencies themselves.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Later on, you only need to specify the **Faces Servlet** in the `web.xml` file to have **RichFaces** working. Take a look to [this entry](http://www.mastertheboss.com/richfaces/richfaces-4-quick-tutorial) too.

Comment: Ok, I added dependencies but it still doesn't work :( What changed it's only that I have now this on each site:
`One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been defined within the view.`

Comment: You need to have `h:head` tag at the beginning of the page to get it working.