# Dependency lost in RichFaces

Tags: java, maven, jsf, richfaces, pom.xml

How to install RichFaces in maven project?

I have my pom.xml but it does not work.

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.jboss.tools.examples</groupId>
<artifactId>mreporte</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>WildFly Quickstarts: mreporte</name>
<description>A starter Java EE 7 webapp project for use on JBoss WildFly / WildFly, generated from the jboss-javaee6-webapp archetype</description>

<url>http://wildfly.org</url>
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
    </license>
</licenses>
  <properties>
<primefaces.version>5.3</primefaces.version>
<org.richfaces.bom.version>4.2.2.Final</org.richfaces.bom.version>
    <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following 
        message: -->
    <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered 
        resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
    <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>

    <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify 
        tested stacks. -->
    <version.jboss.bom>8.2.1.Final</version.jboss.bom>

    <!-- other plugin versions -->
    <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
    <version.surefire.plugin>2.16</version.surefire.plugin>
    <version.war.plugin>2.5</version.war.plugin>

    <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 7 APIs including a Bill
            of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
            of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
            of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools stack (you can
            read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with some extras tools
            for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate
            stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with extras
            from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${org.richfaces.bom.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All 
        of them are provided by JBoss WildFly -->

    <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss WildFly -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
        as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
        in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
    <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
    <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Now we declare any tools needed -->

    <!-- Annotation processor to generate the JPA 2.0 metamodel classes for 
        typesafe criteria queries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Annotation processor that raising compilation errors whenever constraint 
        annotations are incorrectly used. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
    <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and Transactional(JTA) 
        JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.5-beta5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name 
        given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Java EE 7 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- The WildFly plugin deploys your war to a local WildFly container -->
        <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it to run 
            just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
        <!-- Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including Arquillian 
            tests that execute in the specified container -->
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>

        <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests
            in your WildFly instance -->
        <!-- This profile will start a new WildFly instance, and execute the
            test, shutting it down when done -->
        <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-managed -->
        <id>arq-wildfly-managed</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests
            in a remote WildFly instance -->
        <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-remote -->
        <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
            invoking mvn. -->
        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
            will need. -->
        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' 
            folder. -->
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

I also tried following the advice on:

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToAddRichFaces4xToMavenBasedProject

[How to add richfaces to maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675930/how-to-add-richfaces-to-maven-project)

I made some attempts with RichFaces, I saw that I need a dependency

[Dependencia guava](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QjZH.png)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Notes: Maven version --> 3.3.9
       Java --> 1.8

Comment: If you're having problems with RichFaces artifacts don't post the entire POM. What is the problem, are you getting any error during the build?